# Trying to install i-nex

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to install i-nex.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gambas-team/gambas3

: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/i-nex-development-team/daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Did you check that bionic is supported? (it doesn't support anything past 17.04 so I'm betting no).   I don't know what i-nex is, but you'll have to find it elsewhere  (*or look at @DKBose's suggested link*)

Comment: Thanks. Info on i-next is here. http://i-nex.linux.pl/ @DK Bose